# JSF - How to get old and new value when using Primefaces RowEditEvent?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable with 2 columns(name and description) and I want to update my database when a person updates a row and clicks the checkmark which triggers the `execBacking.update` method.

In this method, I get the new values by casting `event.getObject()`, but how can i also get the old values? The name is my primary key so i need the old value to know which row to update in the db.

xhtml page

```
  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{execBacking.update}" update=":execForm:execMessages" /> 

  <p:column headerText="Name">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{exec.name}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{exec.name}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Description">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{exec.description}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{exec.description}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Actions">
    <p:rowEditor />
    <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" type="submit" actionListener="#{execBacking.delete}" update=":execForm:execMessages" >
            <f:attribute name="execName" value="#{exec.name}" />
        </p:commandLink>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Backing bean

```
public void update(RowEditEvent event) {

        Dao dao = new Dao(ds);
        Exec exec = (Exec) event.getObject();
        System.out.println("name = "+exec.getName());  //New name
        System.out.println("desc = "+exec.getDescription());  //New desc
        try {
            // If the new exec was updated successfully
            if(dao.updateExec(accessBacking.getUsername(), null, exec.getName(), exec.getDescription())) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success", "Exec Updated Successfully!"));
            } else {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Error Updating Exec!"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you interested in getting old value of the entire row as a single object or individual columns?

Comment: Either would work. All i need is the original value of `name` since it's the PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend *not* having `name` be your primary key, but instead add an auto-incrementing `id` field and make that your primary key, and **don't** make that field editable by the user.  This guarantees you always have access to the record that you want to update.

Generally speaking it's bad practice to attempt to modify the primary key in a database the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: Can't change the database. There's a 15 year old perl app that i'm rewriting and the primary key is the name. I know it's not the best practice, but it's what I've got to work with.

Comment: Ok... plan B then would be to simply store the old `name` in a second variable and handle it that way

Comment: Ideally I guess i'd like to somehow pass the original value via an f:attribute or f:param or something like that rather than adding a duplicate "name" to my Exec object.

Comment: End result is you'll have to duplicate it somewhere.  If it were me I'd just add an "originalName" field to the Object.  Best advice I can give you.  It can be a transient value

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `ValueChangeListener` on the component you're interested in using:

```
<p:column headerText="Description">
   <p:cellEditor>
      <f:facet name="output">
          <h:outputText value="#{exec.name}" />
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
        <h:inputText value="#{exec.name}">
           <f:valueChangeListener binding="#{keyChangedListener}"/>
           <f:ajax/>
        </h:inputText>
      </f:facet>
   </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

`keyChangeListener` will correspond to an implementation of `ValueChangeListener` and we're using `<f:ajax/>` here to ensure that the `valueChanged` event is fired on the textbox. Otherwise the listener will not be notified. Your listener should look something like:

```
@ManagedBean(name="keyChangedListener")
@ViewScoped
public class KeyChangeListener implements ValueChangeListener{

     public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException{
          Object oldValue = event.getOldValue(); //get the old value
          Object newValue = event.getNewValue(); //get the new value

      }
```

I'm using the `@ViewScoped`here as advised by the JSF Spec, to avoid unwanted side effects.

Comment: But if I use a valueChangeListener, It won't work with `<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{backing.update}" />` will it?

Comment: @Catfish - I can't say for sure, but I can't think of a reason for it not to